# How to send Images via SocketServer in Python 3?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, encode, socketserver

I would like to send images with socketserver of python 3 and I have a problem of encoding.
Do I need to send it in bytes or in text? And do I need to open my image with the 'b' option and to transform it in a particular format?

With previous version of python I could do :

```
image = open('my_image.jpg', 'rb')
image_data = image.read()
image.close()

socketData = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketData.connect((ADDRESS,PORT))

socketData.sendall(image_data)
```

But with python 3, it doesn't work anymore. There are encoding and codecs problems and I don't really understand the using of encode(), decode() or str().

Do you have any idea how I can implement it?

Thanks

Comment: Really? [It seems to work for me](http://i.imgur.com/h3wvN.png). What specific error are you getting?

Comment: In fact, a explained my problem badly. There is something I forgot to add : I have a header to add to my image for my client and my header is in text format. So when I send my data, I have something like this :

    socketData.sendall(header + image_data)

And the error is :
    Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Do I need to convert my header in bytes (if yes how :/) or my image in text ?

Comment: I can send it separately and it works, so it solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I wrote above, your code works as-is currently. To add a header to the data that you want to send over the socket, you first need to know its encoding. Assuming that it is UTF-8, you can do the following:

```
header = "Header！\n"
header_bytes = bytes(header, 'utf-8')
socketData.sendall(header_bytes + image_data)
```

`bytes` type can only be concatenated with `bytes` in Python 3.